# rails3 ajax: What is the best way of persisting local variables via ajax?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

This is how my view looks (please ignore the opening and closing tags):

```
@obj1.leaves.each do |l|
    <div id = "form">
        if <some_condition>
            render :partial => 'shared/view1', :locals => { :l => l }
        else
            render :partial => 'shared/view2', :locals => { :l => l }
        end
    </div>
end
```

And the final action on view1 causes view2 to display and vice versa thru ajax. But when view1 or view2 are rendered the local variable 'l' is not recognized anymore and throws an error causing the forms not to display (except on manual page refresh). What do I do to make the forms work and persisting my 'l'?

Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: My create.js.erb file for view1 (view2 i actually the destroy method so vice versa):

```
$("#form").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render('shared/view2')).html_safe %>")
```

And my actual view:

```
<%= form_for([l, l.likes.build], :remote => true) do |f| %>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Like" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Which fails, the one you show, or the Ajax one that shows the other one?

Comment: the form rendered by ajax fails

Comment: Then showing the part that does that would be helpful.

Comment: there you go.. added the ajax part..

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer.)

```
@obj1.leaves.each do |l|
  partial = <some_condition> ? 'shared/view1' : 'shared/view2'
  render :partial => partial, :locals => { :l => l }
end
```

Locals are just that; local. It's not clear to me what Ajax you're talking about--`replaceWith` just replaces content, it doesn't make a request. If it's all in the same request, you could make `l` an instance variable (`@l`) and see if that clears things up.